# Jquery find parent of child element, then apply action to another child of initial parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to implement a search box that highlights results across multiple div's that are resizable and draggable.

I've gotten to the point where I can search and highlight results, but the action is carried out across all of the div's, not the one that is currently active.  The ideal solution would apply the action to the element being utilized, not all of the available elements.

When someone types in the input field with the `class="sch"`, I'm attempting to find the parent div with `class="resdiv1000"`.  Then I need to traverse down the elements to find the iframe with the `name="resdiv1000"`.

I was attempting to utilize the following code in the jquery below.  It does not work.  The full jquery example is working, but when this snippet is included it breaks.  Why is this happening?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
var test = $(this).closest('div[class^="resdiv"]').children('iframe[name^="resdiv"]');
var page2 = test.contents().find('html');
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="resdiv1000 resizable">
    <div class="checkdrag">
        <div class="backward" onclick="resdiv1000.history.back()">&lt;</div> 
        <div class="forward" onclick="resdiv1000.history.forward()">&gt;</div>
        <span class="rslts-a"></span>
        <input type="text" class="sch" />
    </div>
    <div class="xout">X</div>
    <div id="rescont1000" >
        <iframe src="http://www.Thissite.com/grab.php?item=http://www.mysite.com" name="resdiv1000"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery that I'm using:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sch').bind('keyup change', function(ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();

        // remove any old highlighted terms
         var page2 = $('iframe[name^="resdiv"]').contents().find('html');
         page2.removeHighlight();
        //$('body').removeHighlight();

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if ( searchTerm ) {
            // highlight the new term
            page2.highlight( searchTerm );
            //$('body').highlight( searchTerm );
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet try changing this:

```
var test = $(this).closest('div[class^="resdiv"]').children('iframe[name^="resdiv"]');
```

into this:

```
var test = $(this).closest('div[class^="resdiv"]').find('iframe[name^="resdiv"]');
```

since the argument you're passing to children() only filters direct children of the element and not any descendant.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = $(this).closest('.resdiv').find('iframe');
var page2 = test.contents().find('html');
```

When assigning the test variable, the children method only looks for direct descendants. The iframe is nested in another element. Find is your solution.